Azure Document Intelligence - RequestFailedException: 'Resource not found Status: 404 (Not Found)
I'm trying to get a code sample to use Azure Document Intelligence with files located on an in-house server but I'm getting the following error:
Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Resource not found
Status: 404 (Not Found)
ErrorCode: 404

Content:
{"error":{"code":"404","message":"Resource not found"}}

Headers:
Content-Length: 55
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2024 14:08:41 GMT

I'm following the steps provided in this articleGet started with Document Intelligence but I've adjusted it to use a local file instead of a uri.
This is my code:
string endpoint = "https://<MyServiceInstance>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";
string apiKey = "<MyApiKey>";
string filename = "C:\\..\\MyFile.jpg";

var client = new DocumentIntelligenceClient(new Uri(endpoint), new AzureKeyCredential(apiKey));

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    var result = AnalyzeDocumentAsync(client, stream).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}


static async Task<Operation<AnalyzeResult>> AnalyzeDocumentAsync(
    DocumentIntelligenceClient client, 
    Stream documentStream)
{
    string modelId = "MyModelId";

    var content = new AnalyzeDocumentContent()
    {
         Base64Source = BinaryData.FromStream(documentStream)
    };

    var operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, modelId, content);

    AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;

    Console.WriteLine($"Document was analyzed with model with ID: {result.ModelId}");

    foreach (AnalyzedDocument document in result.Documents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Document of type: {document.DocType}");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DocumentField> fieldKvp in document.Fields)
        {
            string fieldName = fieldKvp.Key;
            DocumentField field = fieldKvp.Value;

            Console.WriteLine($"Field '{fieldName}': ");

            Console.WriteLine($"  Content: '{field.Content}'");
            Console.WriteLine($"  Confidence: '{field.Confidence}'");
        }
    }

    return operation;
}

The line that's throwing the exception is:
var operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, modelId, content);

I'm getting my settings from Azure as per instructed in article:

and my model is a "Custom Model" and I'm using the name of the Id I used when training the model.
Anyone has any ideas what I'm missing?

Use DocumentAnalysisClient, which is the recommended class for interacting with Azure Form Recognizer and Document Intelligence services.


DocumentIntelligenceClient is an outdated configuration Instead of it use DocumentAnalysisClient, which is the recommended class for interacting with Azure Form Recognizer and Document Intelligence services.


Using  AnalyzeDocumentAsync with AnalyzeDocumentContent and Base64Source, which is not the correct approach for current SDK methods.


Use AnalyzeDocumentAsync with a Stream directly, which aligns with the latest SDK methods.

Code:
using Azure;
using Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.DocumentAnalysis;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string endpoint = "https://<YourServiceInstance>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";
            string apiKey = "<YourApiKey>";
            string filename = "C:\\path\\to\\your\\file.pdf"; // Update with your file path
            string modelId = "<YourModelId>"; // Ensure this is the correct model ID

            var client = new DocumentAnalysisClient(new Uri(endpoint), new AzureKeyCredential(apiKey));

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var result = await AnalyzeDocumentAsync(client, modelId, stream);
                Console.WriteLine($"Model ID used: {result.ModelId}");
            }
        }

        static async Task<AnalyzeResult> AnalyzeDocumentAsync(
            DocumentAnalysisClient client,
            string modelId,
            Stream documentStream)
        {
            try
            {
                // Analyze the document with the specified model
                AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, modelId, documentStream);
                AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;

                Console.WriteLine($"Document analyzed with model ID: {result.ModelId}");

                // Process the analyzed document
                foreach (AnalyzedDocument document in result.Documents)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Document has the following fields:");

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DocumentField> fieldKvp in document.Fields)
                    {
                        string fieldName = fieldKvp.Key;
                        DocumentField field = fieldKvp.Value;

                        Console.WriteLine($"Field '{fieldName}': ");
                        Console.WriteLine($"  Content: '{field.Content}'");
                        Console.WriteLine($"  Confidence: '{field.Confidence}'");
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}

Model test in portal for reference:

Result:


Many thanks for that Suresh! I can't believe I wasted so much time on this and you're telling me the DocumentIntelligenceClient is out of date and I got this from Microsoft on the "Get Started". Very frustrating, but happy I can move on at least. Thanks again :).

On this comment:
DocumentIntelligenceClient is an outdated configuration Instead of it use DocumentAnalysisClient, which is the recommended class for interacting with Azure Form Recognizer and Document Intelligence services.
This appears to be inaccurate.
See: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/documentintelligence/Azure.AI.DocumentIntelligence/MigrationGuide.md
"The client DocumentIntelligenceClient has replaced DocumentAnalysisClient"
